# How to add new element to map in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to add an element with the same first key to map and save each element there?

'''

```
        var records = mutableMapOf<Int, Map<Int, List<String>>>()
        records.put(1, mutableMapOf(Pair(2, listOf<String>("first"))))
        records.put(1, mutableMapOf(Pair(3, listOf<String>("second"))))
```

'''

Comment: You might want to consider implementing a data class if you are creating nested maps like this.

In addition, you're trying to map `1` (fine as an `Int`) to `Pair(2, listOf<String>("first"))`.. which is not, itself a `Map<Int, List<String>`, which is what you are telling Kotlin this mutableMap will contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps can only have one value per key, if you add another entry with a key that already exists, it'll overwrite it. You need a value type that's a collection (like `List` or `Set`) that you can put multiple things into.

Assuming you want to use `Int` keys to store items that are `Pair<Int, String>`, you'll need a `MutableMap<Int, MutableList<Pair<Int, String>>>` (or a `Set`, you won't get duplicates and it's unordered usually).

You need to `get` the collection for a key, and then add to it (or whatever you're doing):

```
var records = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<Pair<Int, String>>>()
// this creates a new empty list if one doesn't exist for this key yet
records.getOrPut(1) { mutableListOf() }.add(Pair(2, "first"))
records.getOrPut(1) { mutableListOf() }.add(3 to "second") // another way to make a Pair
println(records)

>> {1=[(2, first), (3, second)]}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/AlrSG0KH-

That's a bit wordy so you might want to make some nice `addRecord(key, value)` etc functions that let you access those inner lists more easily